# Reading from cache instead of MySQL, except the first user who creates it (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, caching

In my web application, many users post data and then request calculated result. Since the calculation is time-consuming, I want to cache the result of the first user and let other users read the cache.

```
if ( Cache::exist( $dataId ) ) {
    return Cache::read( $dataId );
}
$result = getDataFromDatabaseAndCalcResult( $dataId );
Cache::write( $dataId, $result );
return $result;
```

However, when I tried this program, more than 100 requests come in simultaneously and most of them find no cache, so they all call getDataFromDatabaseAndCalcResult method. The server runs out of CPU resource.

Is there any idea for that only the first user calls getDataFromDatabaseAndCalcResult. Should I implement some job-queue or mysql-locking-system or something?

Comment: This is called the "dog pile" problem. If you google it you'll find some solutions.

Comment: *Off topic:* I love your naming conventions "`getDataFromDatabaseAndCalcResult`" :P

Comment: But yes, your problem is that which Barmer stated.